# Browser consider element still hovered when it moved away by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've made a small example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3hFrJ/

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'left': '200px'})
}
```

If you hover red div it becomes blue. Then you click on it and it moves away from mouse pointer but browser considers it hovered until you move mouse. (I have google-chrome browser)

How can I ask browser to refresh hover state for elements?

Comment: What exactly you're looking for ? Are you looking for **When the div slides the color changes automatically without movement of mouse?**

Comment: I need hover state to be reset. It is not about color, my elements becomes bigger on hover. And when my elements pass cursor by they become bigger but not become smaller when they out

Comment: I'm not able to see any kind of changes that you're describing but you can use `border` to make that a fixed effect. and `border-color` will be `transparent`.

Comment: There is no scale effect on jsfiddle. Scale effect on hover is in my project. I just want to know if it is possible to reset hover state

Comment: Actually your code works as expected in FF26, but not in Chrome31 or IE11.

Comment: In linux firefox26 and chrome31 act the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding `hover` effect using jquery rather than using css
and then reset the `hover` state on click event

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'blue'});
}, function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
});
$('#element').click(function(){
    if ($(this).css('left') == '200px')
        $(this).animate({'left': '20px'})   /// move left
    else
        $(this).animate({'left': '200px'})  /// move right
    $(this).trigger('mouseout');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3hFrJ/4/) is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hFrJ/4/) link

Though this is also not perfect (as to refresh the hover state as soon as element is out of   cursor scope )  but still you can choose to reset the hover state as soon as the element is clicked or after the animation completes

Comment: I just needed how to realize hover with hover reset ability. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some extra markup with a container that is a little bigger and then apply your transforms on your child. so you won't get the flickering effect